# Excel Conditional Formating

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have 3 row and 4 column table. How to BOLD entire row "A2" to "D2" if cell "A2" is highest score in column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, the formula `$A2=MAX($A3,$A4)` applied to `$A$2:$D$5` (adjust that as necessary).

Comment: Not working. And one more thing, the highest score maybe at cell "A3" or "A4".

Comment: Just change the formula to `$A$2=MAX($A$2:$A$4)` and it should work (i.e. change 3 to 2 and all references should be absolute)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer...

```
=SEARCH(MAX($A$2:$A$4),$A2:$A40)
```

Apply to

```
=$B$2:$E$4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula.

```
=$A2=MAX($A$2:$A$40)
```

[image]